# Categorize dataset in R

Tags: r

I am having an issue with categorizing a dataset.

The dataset is an matrix in which the rows are observations, and the columns are the features.  Each features value is between 0 - 1. The dataset is used for training purposes, and since the method I am going to use is vary sensitive to small variation, the dataset has to formatted to not be sensitive.

My idea was that instead of providing the raw data i want to bin the feature values into bins according to their numeric value, and provide the **middle value of the bin** as the training data for the training.

Ex. 
bins being (1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-7,7-8,8-9,9-10)

```
dataset #original dataset
>         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    8.1    5.3   10    4.4    4.6
[2,]    5.2   10    3.2    9.3    3.5
[3,]    7.3    1.6    9    8.9    8.4
[4,]    6.4    2.8    8    6.5    9.3
[5,]   10    4.3    2.2    1.1    5.3

transformed_dataset #binned dataset


>         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    8.5    5.5   9.5   4.5    4.5
[2,]    5.5   9.5   3.5    9.5   3.5
[3,]    7.5    1.5   8.5    8.5    8.5
[4,]    6.5    2.5   8.5    6.5    9.5
[5,]    9.5    4.5  2.5    1.5    5.5
```

I am not sure on how i should bin the data like this, and give it as input for `naiveBayes` from the `library("lattice")`. I know that `signif` is capable of rounding the value to a giving number of digits, and thus "bining it", but i can't actually determine the number of bins.

Binning seems a way to improve the classification. But how to provide it as a input, that I am not certain of.

**Updata about the data.frame**

I think i forgot to mention it, but the data is stored in a `data.frame`, and the way i access the data is by $data.  the data.frame all provide labels for each observation which can be accessed by $labels.

Comment: Why not just round the number down? That way your bins are represented as a single number instead of number-number.

Comment: Ohh.. Good idea. That way i could create easier bins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm. You may have some trouble with the data types here, because `matrix` class does not work well with factors - and the binning intervals are best described by factors.

In order to do the binning, you can use the `cut` function from the base R installation, such as:

```
> data <- c(1,2,4,1,5,3,3,5,2,2,5,5,5,7,8,9,5,3,2,6,8,9,3,1)
> breaks <- c(0, 3, 6, 9)
> cut(data, breaks=breaks)
 [1] (0,3] (0,3] (3,6] (0,3] (3,6] (0,3] (0,3] (3,6] (0,3] (0,3] (3,6] (3,6]
 [13] (3,6] (6,9] (6,9] (6,9] (3,6] (0,3] (0,3] (3,6] (6,9] (6,9] (0,3] (0,3]
 Levels: (0,3] (3,6] (6,9]
```

Or, using the left interval:

```
> cut(data, breaks=breaks, right=FALSE)
 [1] [0,3) [0,3) [3,6) [0,3) [3,6) [3,6) [3,6) [3,6) [0,3) [0,3) [3,6) [3,6)
[13] [3,6) [6,9) [6,9) <NA>  [3,6) [3,6) [0,3) [6,9) [6,9) <NA>  [3,6) [0,3)
Levels: [0,3) [3,6) [6,9)
```

Notice that the breaks you provide should cover the entire dataset, or else you will get some `NA`s.

Comment: Thanks for the response... @Teja K came with an idea that seem to much easier and more applicable to me case. Problem is though i am not able to determine the number of bins.   Could the categories be defined as the middle value of the bin instead?

Comment: well, you can use something like `bins <- seq(0, 10, length.out=XXX)`, and keep changing the length.out to have more or less bins

Comment: would it be possible to have the middle value of the bins rather than this (0,3]...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be like this:

```
d <- matrix(c(8.1, 5.3, 10, 4.4, 4.6,
              5.2, 10, 3.2, 9.3, 3.5,
              7.3, 1.6, 9, 8.9, 8.4,
              6.4, 2.8, 8, 6.5, 9.3,
              10, 4.3, 2.2, 1.1, 5.3), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)

d <- as.data.frame(apply(d, 2, function(column) {
  as.factor(round(column+0.5)-0.5)
}))
```

Leading to results:

```
> d
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1 8.5 5.5 9.5 4.5 4.5
2 5.5 9.5 3.5 9.5 3.5
3 7.5 1.5 9.5 8.5 8.5
4 6.5 2.5 7.5 6.5 9.5
5 9.5 4.5 2.5 1.5 5.5
```

After the transformation, the columns of your dataset are factors, meaning that `naiveBayes` will not treat them as numeric but as categorical variables.

```
> class(d[,1])
[1] "factor"
> levels(d[,1])
[1] "5.5" "6.5" "7.5" "8.5" "9.5"
```

Note that the trick of adding and removing 0.5 will fail if you have any value equal to 0 - it will assign it to level "0" instead of "0.5". You could solve it adding this line to the function:

```
column[which(column == 0)] <- 0.5
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you way of doing it seem to be right, but it I want to control the number of bins i create such that i could find the optimum number..

Comment: Not sure I understand how do you want to define the bins, anyway if you want to control the bins maybe you could use `cut` as in the answer by @andrechalom. You can put whatever breaks you want, don't have to be distributed evenly, and once your column is defined as categorical, the level descriptions are only for readability, you could even change them, the algorithm is not going to use the description of the levels. Good luck.

Comment: The output should not be (0,3] but rather a the middle value of the bin interval. But yes. `Cut`could be used.

Comment: I mean: the output is meaningless. You can change it to the middle value of the bin interval if you want. Just reassign using `levels(column) <- c("level1", "level", ...)`. Cheers.